# msmdpump.dll ignoring Basic Authentication

Tags: ssl, iis-7, https, ssas, basic-authentication

I have a website setup with require SSL and HTTPS binding to connect to my analysis services over IIS7.
Connection works although regardless the credentials in parse in via Excel, it keeps authenticating on AS as IUSR.
Any help would be appreciated, it's driving me nuts.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Is Basic Authentication enabled in IIS under the application? You might be able to use Fiddler to see what is being passed.

Also, I would check the Office Data Connection in Excel to see if the connection string might give any clues.